# How to set shadows in React Native for android?

Tags: react-native, shadow

Hi am trying to set a shadow for my fab but my attempts has failed so far i tried setting shadow props but that is for ios only so i tried to play with `elevation` property but it doesn't look right.

Here's what i tried

```
  <View
    style={{
      width: 56,
      height: 56,
      elevation: 2,
      borderRadius: 28,
      marginBottom: 3,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(231,76,60,1)',
    }}
  ></View>
```

What i need to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Adding the CSS property `elevation: 1` renders shadow in Android without installing any 3rd party library.

`elevation` is an Android-only style property available on the `View` elements.

See: [React Native Docs for the `elevation` style property](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#elevation-android)

---

If you're open to 3rd party software, another way to get shadows for android is to install [`react-native-shadow`](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow).

Example (adapted from the readme):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

import { BoxShadow } from "react-native-shadow";

export default class ShadowButton extends Component {
  render() {
    const shadowOpt = {
      width: 160,
      height: 170,
      color: "#000",
      border: 2,
      radius: 3,
      opacity: 0.2,
      x: 0,
      y: 3,
      style: { marginVertical: 5 }
    };

    return (
      <BoxShadow setting={shadowOpt}>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            width: 160,
            height: 170,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderRadius: 3,
            // marginVertical: 5,
            overflow: "hidden"
          }}
        >
          ...
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </BoxShadow>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding css property `elevation: 1` renders shadow in Android without installing any 3rd party library. I tested it with React Native 0.52

Comment: Be careful when using `elevation` as it won't respect your settings for `shadow`, such as the color and offset.

Comment: this lib, how to do if I don't know the specify width height of children. . . cuz it require.

Comment: @LeangSocheat Did you ever figure out what do if you don't know the width or height beforehand? I am having the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @FuzzyTree about the react-native-shadow module seems missing the main.

Comment: as others pointed out, is not possible change the shadow color from its default as black.

Comment: Elevation does not work without backgroundColor (as per Asad's answer)

Answer (score 118):

The `elevation` style property on Android does not work unless `backgroundColor` has been specified for the element.

[Android - elevation style property does not work without backgroundColor](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10411)

Example:

```
{
  shadowColor: 'black',
  shadowOpacity: 0.26,
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
  shadowRadius: 10,
  elevation: 3,
  backgroundColor: 'white'
}
```

Comment: This really needs more up votes, i had no idea why it wasn't working

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The solution works for both Android and iOS without installing third-party libraries.

Comment: this is the key point which i was missing.... this need more upvotes

Comment: This is the solution!!! Background Color makes it work!!!! Thanks ^_^

Comment: Accepted answer should be this.

Answer (score 81):

Another solution without using a third-party library is using `elevation`.

Pulled from react-native documentation.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html

> (Android-only) Sets the elevation of a view, using Android's
>   underlying elevation API. This adds a drop shadow to the item and
>   affects z-order for overlapping views. Only supported on Android 5.0+,
>   has no effect on earlier versions.

`elevation` will go into the `style` property and it can be implemented like so.

```
<View style={{ elevation: 2 }}>
    {children}
</View>
```

The higher the elevation, the bigger the shadow. Hope this helps!

Comment: why elevation attribute is written inside 2 braces?

Comment: @divine the outer bracket is for JS interpolation, the inner is for an object

Comment: This only does a shadow on the bottom of a view, it doesn't allow you to do shadows on the other sides

Comment: Correct, there are many things iOS handles better when using react-native and shadows are one of them.

Comment: Be careful with `elevation` though – like it says in the docs, it "affects z-order for overlapping views" – it basically acts like a `zIndex` that you can't override and can cause really confusing behaviours. For example, in a SectionList with sticky section headers, if you put `elevation: 3` on the items in the list they will suddenly start going _over_ the headers, hiding them from view (on android only of course). This is nearly impossible to debug!

Comment: This will work for all android version. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview

Answer (score 48):

You can try

```
//ios    
shadowOpacity: 0.3,
shadowRadius: 3,
shadowOffset: {
    height: 0,
    width: 0
},
//android
elevation: 1
```

Comment: Elevation does not create a large enough or configurable shadow for android - react-native-shadow seems like the best option

Answer (score 12):

The following will help you to give each `Platform` the styling you want:

```
import { Text, View, Platform } from 'react-native';

......
<View style={styles.viewClass}></View>
......


const styles = {
viewClass: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    ...Platform.select({
        ios: {
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        },
        android: {
            elevation: 1

        },
      }),
}
};
```

Comment: It's not needed to specify the platform since in iOS elevation property will be ignored

Comment: @cody yes, you are right! but my example shows how to set styles for different platforms.

Answer (score 7):

for an android screen you can use this property `elevation`.

for example :

```
 HeaderView:{
    backgroundColor:'#F8F8F8',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    height:60,
    paddingTop:15,

    //Its for IOS
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,

    // its for android 
    elevation: 5,
    position:'relative',

},
```

Comment: It's working but, in Android, how can I change shadow color?

Answer (score 6):

You can use my **react-native-simple-shadow-view**

- This enables almost identical shadow in Android as in iOS
- No need to use elevation, works with the same shadow parameters of iOS (shadowColor, shadowOpacity, shadowRadius, offset, etc.) so you don't need to write platform specific shadow styles
- Can be used with semi-transparent views
- Supported in android 18 and up

Comment: can replace Animated.View with it ?

Comment: Try: const AnimatedShadowView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ShadowView). It should work

Comment: I really this is the best solution ! Not very dependent on many risqued dependencies. It works for me except that the ShadowView doesn't support specific corner radius props (borderTopRightRadius, borderTopLeftRadius, borderBottomRightRadius, borderBottomLeftRadius).

Answer (score 5):

Just use 'elevation' property to get shadow in android. something like below

```
const Header = () => {
    // const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewStyle}>    
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Albums</Text>
      </View>
    )
}


const styles = {
    viewStyle:{
        backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8',
        justifyContext:'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding:16,
        elevation: 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I added **borderBottomWidth: 0** and it worked fine for me in android.

Answer (score 4):

Also i'd like to add that if one's trying to apply shadow in a TouchableHighlight Component in which child has borderRadius, the parent element (TouchableHighlight) also need the radius set in order to elevation prop work on Android.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented CardView for react-native with elevation, that support android(All version) and iOS. Let me know is it help you or not. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview

```
import CardView from 'react-native-cardview'
<CardView
          cardElevation={2}
          cardMaxElevation={2}
          cornerRadius={5}>
          <Text>
              Elevation 0
          </Text>
</CardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't do that in android, because if you see the docs about shadow only **Support IOS** [see doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props)

The best option you can install 3rd party [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is this one!

[Click here to see preview of simple drop shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEwrj.png)

Does not flicker when rendering collapse elements:

```
    const styles = {
        simpleShadow: {
            borderTopWidth: 0.5,
            borderRightWidth: 1,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderLeftWidth: 0.5,
            borderTopColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            borderRightColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
            borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
            borderLeftColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',

            backgroundColor: 'white',
            margin: 10,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10
        }
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.simpleShadow}>
            <Text>Simple Shadow</Text>
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

#### Generating shadows for a circle, react native, android

Based on the answers here, and on text that I found in github (react-native-shadow), I made few tests and thought that some people may find the following helpful.

- The tests are on a circular button
- The environment: Windows 10 PC, react-native using react-native-shadow (which doesn't work well for a circle) and react-native's elevation parameter (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props#elevation) with different values, running on an android emulator (genymotion)

#### Here is how the screen looks like:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableHighlight, Text } from 'react-native';
import { BoxShadow } from 'react-native-shadow'

export default class ShadowsTest extends Component {

  render() {
    const shadowOpt = {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: "#000",
      border: 2,
      radius: 50,
      opacity: 0.8,
      x: 3,
      y: 3,
      //style: { marginVertical: 5 }
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Header
          text={"Shadows Test"} />

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ margin: 10, alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={{
              position: 'relative',
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              borderRadius: 50,
              borderWidth: 0.8,
              borderColor: '#000',
              // marginVertical:5,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              overflow: "hidden" }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                0: plain border
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

          <View style={{ margin: 10, alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <BoxShadow setting={ shadowOpt }>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{
                position: 'relative',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderRadius: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#aaa',
                // marginVertical:5,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                overflow: "hidden" }}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  1: RN shadow package
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </BoxShadow>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ margin: 10, alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{
                position: 'relative',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderRadius: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#aaa',
                // marginVertical:5,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                overflow: "hidden",
                shadowOffset: { width: 15, height: 15 },
                shadowColor: "black",
                shadowOpacity: 0.9,
                shadowRadius: 10,
               }}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  2: vanilla RN: shadow (may work on iOS)
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
          <View style={{ margin: 10, alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{
                position: 'relative',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderRadius: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#aaa',
                // marginVertical:5,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                overflow: "hidden",
                elevation: 15,
               }}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  3: vanilla RN: elevation only (15)
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: 30 }}>
          <View style={{ margin: 10, alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{
                position: 'relative',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderRadius: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#aaa',
                // marginVertical:5,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                overflow: "hidden",
                elevation: 5,
               }}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  4: vanilla RN: elevation only (5)
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
          <View style={{ margin: 10, alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{
                position: 'relative',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderRadius: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#aaa',
                // marginVertical:5,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                overflow: "hidden",
                elevation: 50,
               }}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  5: vanilla RN: elevation only (50)
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it only worked for my by adding `borderColor: 'transparent'` (or any other color). My style output looks like this:

```
{
        borderColor: "transparent", // Required to show shadows on Android for some reason !?!?
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 0,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 5,

        elevation: 15,
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) library is already mentioned in the answers, but it seems to be abandoned for several years.

A modern alternative, which solved my issue with consistent shadows across both iOS and Android was [react-native-shadow-2](https://github.com/SrBrahma/react-native-shadow-2).

**EDIT:** I ended up using the native shadow solutions (and `elevation` for Android). According to the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props#shadowcolor), Android API 28 and above supports `shadowColor` on elevated elements and it works well for my case.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not look "natural"

Comment: It looks really different from the iOS shadow or even web CSS shadow. To me it seems like a glowing outline around the element. Let me say that this doesn't mean the library cannot be used, it just didn't provide the styles I was looking for.

Comment: Pretty sure it's all about fine-tuning the settings and props until you get something that looks normal

Comment: Yes, possible. I feel I lacked some controls for tweaking stuff like blur & spread radius (coming from web), which was somehow possible with the iOS-supported shadow props in ReactNative. Anyways, I edited my answer to avoid potential misleading.

Answer (score 1):

**elevation** still no work in Expo v30 && React-native v0.55.4. 
I have tried the all answers here.

Also, don't try **react-native-shadow** - their shadow rendering is terrible. 
So, I am continuing the research.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why elevation is not working on Expo. Mine is SDK 32 :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `elevation: 3` and you should see the shadow in bottom of component without a 3rd party lib. At least in RN 0.57.4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem shadow/elevation not showing on Android with elevation:2. Then i noticed that the view element is fool width, so I added margin:2 to the view element and elevation properly appeared.

Style:

```
    margin: 2,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 1.41,
    elevation: 2
```

Android:
[image]

iOS:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be able to work with both mobile OS's and web I did the following:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

   ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 3,
        shadowOffset: {
          height: 0,
          width: 0,
        },
        android: {
          elevation: 1,
        },
        web: {
          boxShadow: '2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        },
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  shadowColor: '#d8d8d8',
  shadowRadius: 10,
  elevation: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'Color code'
}
```

You can set `height` and `width` as well on the `View` style.

Answer (score 0):

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const ViewShadow = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.box}>{children}</View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    box: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: "fff",
        // Android
        elevation: 8,
        // shadow color
        shadowColor: "blue",
        //iOS
        shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 5 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    },
});

export default ViewShadow;
```