# I am not able to see the shadow on my app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to appy shadow to my text in the android app using react native but i am not able to see the shadow at all.
This is my code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
viewStyle:{
    backgroundColor:'pink',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    height:60,
},
textStyle:{
    fontSize:20
},
shadow:{shadowColor:'black',
    shadowOffset:{width:10,height:10},
    shadowOpacity:0.2
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Android everything is normal.

[These are properties that only apply to iOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props):

- shadowOffset;
- shadowOpacity;
- shadowRadius.

To manage the shadow on Android you have to use the [elevation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#elevation-android) parameter.

Here you can find more detailed answers: [How to set shadows in React Native for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320131/how-to-set-shadows-in-react-native-for-android)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! I was using android.