# Tailwind Css in React Native Box Shadow

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css

I am new to react native. I am trying to apply a shadow effect on a restaurant component I created. Unfortunately I cant get the shadow to take effect. All other styling works. I am using tailwind css for this project. Configuration for tailwind is ok. The only problem is shadowing so far. I have tried to apply shadowing to other components but the results are the same, no effect is observed. Where am I going wrong or what am I not seeing.

```
<TouchableOpacity className="bg-white mr-3 shadow">
  <Image 
    source={{
      uri: imgUrl,
    }}
    className="h-36 w-36 rounded-sm"
  />
  <View>
    <Text className="font-bold text-lg pt-2">{title}</Text>
    <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-1">
      <StarIcon color="green" opacity={0.5} size={22} />
      <Text className="text-xs text-gray-500">
        <Text className="text-green-500">{rating}</Text> : {genre}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-1">
      <LocationMarkerIcon color="gray" size={22} opacity={0.4}/>
      <Text className="text-xs text-gray-500"> Nearby : {address}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 3):

***TailwindCSS in React Native is: [nativewind](https://www.nativewind.dev)***
Shadow doesn't work for android devices on nativewind.
You should use External Styling instead of nativewind shadow properties like:

1. import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"

   ```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       shadow: {
           shadowColor: "#000",
           shadowOffset: {
               width: 0,
               height: 3,
           },
           shadowOpacity: 0.27,
           shadowRadius: 4.65,

           elevation: 6,
       }
   })
   export default styles
   ```
2. **Usage:** `<View className="...." style={styles.shadow} />`

Answer (score 1):

first of all your view that have shadow must have a backgroundColor, even white, and your style is something like this:
style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', shadowColor:'#000', shadowOffset:{width:0, height:3}, shadowOpacity:0.5, elevation:3}}

Comment: backgroundColor is not a must when working with tailwind css, it is an added option.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow doesn't work for android devices on tailwind css. The work around I used was to set the style prop to elevation:2 , the higher the number the darker the shadow.
`<TouchableOpacity className="mr-3 bg-white" style={{ elevation:2 }}>`
[enter link description here][1]

[1]: [How to set shadows in React Native for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320131/how-to-set-shadows-in-react-native-for-android) this question was well addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

instead of shadow you can simply replace **t.shadow, t.shadowMd, t.shadowLg, t.shadow2xl**

tailwindCSS classes are somewhat different for react-native-tailwindcss

still confused, please refer [here](https://tvke.github.io/react-native-tailwindcss/effects/box-shadow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays shadow prop works well in NativeWind.

Take my code as example:

```
<View className="flex-1 bg-white p-4">
    <View className="flex-1 bg-blue-500 rounded-2xl shadow shadow-black/>
</View>
```

It's handled both Android and iOS with no problem

Just remember sometimes you'll need to add a background color to work
See more in the docs [here](https://www.nativewind.dev/tailwind/effects/box-shadow)

[Box with shadow-2xl applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9F6F.png)

[Without Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6VKp.png)

Comment: It's important to mention that shadow is not visible without defining a shadow color, in this case `shadow-black`